# Roadtrip in Mongolia WITHOUT guide possible?

Tags: road-trips, guides, mongolia

My friend and I are planning a trip in Mongolia this summer. We saw on the internet that most people hire a driver and a guide. We couldn't find anyone talking about going there without a guide.

Is it possible to just rent a vehicle (motorbike) for 14 days in Ulan Bator and travel freely through the country?

Comment: I see the word "moto" created a bit of uncertainty (see the edit history). Do you mean a motorbike?

Comment: motobike yes sorry, english is not my monthertongue ;-)

Answer (score 6):

There's no legal reason a driver and/or guide are required. But, it's advisable.

Mongolia is empty. The size of western Europe, and then some, with 1-2 million people living outside of the capital, you're likely to find absolutely nothing, if you go for a long drive.

A guide will know where to go and how to get there. But, will also be able to talk to the few locals you encounter and, most importantly, typically is able to fix a car or a bike with duct tape and rubber bands, so to speak. Wherever you find yourself.

Comment: I wonder what's the Mongolian for `MacGyver`. :D